# LoaderManager LoaderCallback Object

Tags: java, android

Hi please can someone assist I am trying to create a basic loader. All the documentation that I have seen around Loaders involves the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
                    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CONTACTS_LOADER_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACTS_LOADER_ID,
                                  null,
                                  this);
    }
```

However I always receive an error on the "this" in initLoader, wrong 3rd argument required android.app.LoaderManager. LoaderCallbacks.

Comment: Did you implement `onCreateLoader`, `onLoadFinished` and `onLoaderReset` ?

Comment: yes I did thanks solution below worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I always receive an error on the "this" in initLoader, wrong
>   3rd argument required android.app.LoaderManager. LoaderCallbacks.

then you have imported `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` from the support library. You can either change the `import` to the native support, or extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` and use `getSupportLoaderManager()`

Comment: thanks worked like a charm... used your second suggested approach. What did you mean by "change the import to native support"

Comment: for native I meant what's is shipped directly with the Operation System installed on your phone

Comment: sorry last thing I promise... how would you change it to native support

Comment: I wouldn't. I would use the support library. If you need to use the *native* support, just import the correct version of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`. In your case `import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`